# VERY peculiar AS3 auto-format bug (Flash CS6)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm making a game and noticed the autoformat wasn't agreeing with a certain piece of code so I set up a test in another class and got a repeat result, changing the code inside the else statement prevents the error though there's absolutely no reason I can see why it'd occur in the first place, any wisdom to offer? If someone else can replicate this error that'd also be worth knowing about.

**Unformatted:**

```
package  {
public class someClass {
    public function someFunction()
    {
        // code
    }
    function activateForage(currentKinsmen)
    {
        if (getStockID("berry") == 0)
        {
            createStock("food", "berry", Math.ceil(Math.random()*1));
        }
        else
        {       
            listPanel.stockDivider.getChildByName("stock"+getStockID("berry")).stockQuantity += Math.ceil(Math.random()*1);
        }       
    }
    function anotherFunction ()
    {
        // more code
    }
}
}
```

**Formatted:**

```
package 
{
public class someClass
{
    public function someFunction()
    {
        // code
    }
    function activateForage(currentKinsmen)
    {
        if (getStockID("berry") == 0)
        {
            createStock("food", "berry", Math.ceil(Math.random()*1));
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    listPanel.stockDivider.getChildByName("stock"+getStockID("berry")).stockQuantity += Math.ceil(Math.random()*1);
    };
};
function anotherFunction()
{
    // more code
}
}
}
```

Auto-formatting the code twice results in this error:

```
Line 26 1087: Syntax error: extra characters found after end of program.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will fix error on its own, but you should add ":void" to functions, eg:

```
function anotherFunction():void
```

Im assuming you have strict errors turned off? It might seem easier to have them turned off, but in the long-term it will save you lots of time with them switched on.

For starters, it will point out that you have missed off ":void"

Comment: Thanks for the input, it didn't fix the issue though. How do I enable strict errors? I couldn't find an option in the preferences menu.

Comment: not sure if same for cs6 (i have cs5); actionscript settings -> enable "strict mode"

Comment: Nope, can't seem to find it still.